# Javascript call to VB postback function causing unexpected call error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, modalpopupextender

Here is the VB code:

```
 Dim button As New Button
 Dim xpanel As New Panel
 button.Text = "Submit"
 button.ID = "button"
 button.Height = "40"
 button.Attributes.Add("Autopostback", "true")
 button.Attributes.Add("Onclick", "Submit_Click") <----commented
 button.Attributes.Add("RunAt", "server")
 Dim trigger As New AsyncPostBackTrigger()
 trigger.ControlID = "button"
 trigger.EventName = "Submit_Click"
 AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf Submit_Click
 xpanel.Controls.Add(button)
 Dim literalx As New Literal
 submitplaceholder.Controls.Add(literalx)
 submitplaceholder.Controls.Add(xpanel)
```

The setup is: from inside an updatepanel, a button is clicked which fires javascript (a thatbutton.onclick function) on a hidden button at the bottom of the page, which then in turn executes a "click" on an ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender , causing a modal window to pop up that was dynamically populated on page_load with the button above (and other info, but that's unimportant for this).
So far, there are no post backs.

Now we have click the button that page. I want it to post back and call the function Submit_Click. I don't care what the function is actually called and I know _Click's are reserved, but nonetheless : It fires the function but always errors out which causes undesirable behavior.

Something isn't right and I cannot for the life of me think of anything else to try. Using on the property OnClick and then making it autopostback doesn't seem to work with dynamically populating the control. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you executing that code? I mean, in which page event? Load? Init?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

button.Attributes is a collection of HTML attributes, so that won't work the way you want.

Try this:

```
button.UseSubmitBehavior = True
AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf  Submit_Click
```

instead of

```
button.Attributes.Add("Autopostback", "true")
button.Attributes.Add("Onclick", "Submit_Click") <----commented
button.Attributes.Add("RunAt", "server")
```

Comment: USesubmitbehavior  did it. I appreciate it!